# Disk full for unknown reason - BTRFS partition filled up with garbage data

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, disk-space, btrfs

On my Debian Linux laptop a couple of days ago I got my 23GB root EXT4 partition full (probably I installed more software than I expected).

Since I have plenty of space in my BTRFS home partition, 466GB of which 400GB available, I moved the contents of `/usr/share/doc` into `/home/share/doc`, and I created a link `/usr/share/doc -> /home/share/doc`. The size of this `doc` directory was around 2.4GB.

After this change, the system has been working correctly for the past 24 hours.

All at once I got the KDE menu bar and the desktop environment disappear, with only the applications' windows still open. I switched to the command line, and with `df -h` I found out that all the 466GB of my home partition are used.

With `tree --du -h .` from `/home`, I get "4.8G used", a realistic figure.

So, who is right? `df` or `tree`? Where do the remaining 460GB come from?

Since the `doc` directory I copied is still 2.4GB, I suspect that moving it and creating the link is not the reason of my problem.

How can I fix this and get a stable system back?

---

Update:

```
sudo btrfs filesystem usage -h -T /home

Overall:
    Device size:         465.66GiB
    Device allocated:    465.66GiB
    Device unallocated:      0.00B
    Device missing:          0.00B
    Used:                464.28GiB
    Free (estimated):     64.00KiB  (min: 64.00KiB)
    Data ratio:               1.00
    Metadata ratio:           1.00
    Global reserve:      490.34MiB  (used: 0.00B)

                   Data        Metadata    System
Id Path            single      single      single      Unallocated
-- --------------- ---------- ----------- ----------- ------------
 1 /dev/nvme0n1p9  463.65GiB   2.01GiB      4.00MiB          0.00B
-- --------------- ---------- ----------- ----------- ------------
Total              463.65GiB   2.01GiB      4.00MiB          0.00B
Used               463.65GiB 644.72MiB     80.00KiB          0.00B
```

---

Debian 9.5
Dell Precision 7720
home directory: BTRFS
/ directory: EXT4

Comment: Three thoughts: (1) If a filesystem is full and files within sum up to a lot smaller size, it may be because some file(s) is still open (and maybe growing) after being unlinked. Assuming this is the case, some process probably has gone awry. (2) A Btrfs subvolume mounted *elsewhere* (or not at all) cannot be seen by `tree /home`, yet `df` prints what the filesystem *as a whole* reports to it. (3) What `df` prints for Btrfs mountpoints might be strange sometimes because calculating free space on Btrfs is tricky. You may get clearer… no, different picture with `btrfs filesystem df /mountpoint`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - I updated my question.